# How many derangements on a set $[n]$ does there exist such that $\sigma(n)\ne n-1$ ,$\sigma(n-1)\ne n-2$,$\sigma(n-2)\ne n-3$

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, derangements

> How many derangements on a set $[n]$ does there exist such that $\sigma(n)\ne n-1$ ,$\sigma(n-1)\ne n-2$,$\sigma(n-2)\ne n-3$

Define :
$$ \zeta_{n}=\left\{\sigma \in S_n:\forall k \in [n]:\sigma(k) \ne k , \sigma(n)=n-1\right\}$$

$$ \zeta_{n-1}=\left\{\sigma \in S_n:\forall k \in [n]:\sigma(k) \ne k ,\sigma(n-1)=n-2\right\}$$

$$ \zeta_{n-2}=\left\{\sigma \in S_n:\forall k \in [n]:\sigma(k) \ne k ,\sigma(n-2)=n-3\right\}$$

Then we want :
$$!n-\left( \bigcup_{i=0}^{2}\zeta_{n-i}\right)$$
Which is equivalent to :

$$!n-\zeta_{n}-\zeta_{n-1}-\zeta_{n-2}+\zeta_{n}\cap \zeta_{n-1}+\zeta_{n}\cap \zeta_{n-2}+\zeta_{n-1}\cap \zeta_{n-2}-\zeta_{n}\cap \zeta_{n-1} \cap \zeta_{n-2}$$

The size of the sets $\zeta_{n},\zeta_{n-1},\zeta_{n-2}$ are the same and is equal to $\frac{D_n}{n-1}$.

For $\zeta_{n}\cap \zeta_{n-1}$ there are two cases,depending on whether $\sigma(n-2)=n$ or not we have $D_{n-3}+D_{n-2}$ selections.

For $\zeta_{n-1}\cap \zeta_{n-2}$ there are two cases,depending on whether $\sigma(n-3)=n-1$ or not we have$D_{n-3}+D_{n-2}$ selections.

For $\zeta_{n}\cap \zeta_{n-2}$ there are eight cases:

Either $\sigma(n-1)=n,\sigma(n-3)=n-2$ or $\sigma(n-1)=n,\sigma(n-3)\ne n-2$ or $\sigma(n-1) \ne n,\sigma(n-3)=n-2$ or $\sigma(n-1) \ne n,\sigma(n-3)\ne n-2$.
The other cases are the same but we explore the permutations on $\sigma(n-1)=n-2,\sigma(n-3)=n$,gathering all of them gives $2\left(D_{n-4}+2D_{n-3}+D_{n-2}\right)$ cases.

Now consider $\zeta_{n}\cap \zeta_{n-1} \cap \zeta_{n-2}$,depending on whether $\sigma(n-3)=n$ or not we have $D_{n-4}+D_{n-3}$          selections.

So summing the cases gives the answer:$$D_n-3\frac{D_n}{n-1}+D_{n-3}+D_{n-2}+2\left(D_{n-4}+2D_{n-3}+D_{n-2}\right)+D_{n-3}+D_{n-2}-D_{n-4}-D_{n-3}$$
Which is equivalent to:

$$D_n-3\frac{D_n}{n-1}+5D_{n-3}+4D_{n-2}+D_{n-4}$$
I'm not sure if the answer is right,so can someone check that?(I have not tried to rewrite the last expression in its simplest form).

Comment: What's the definition of $D_n$? Do you want to check your progress so far and continue the proof, or any other proof will do?

Comment: @Saad,both,I want to know why my proof does not work and want to know does not exist any other (better) proof of that.

Comment: I imagine $D_n = !n = $ no. of derangements of size $n$.

Comment: @antkam,yes exactly

Comment: Your solution looks right to me but I cannot see why the size of $\zeta_{n}\cap \zeta_{n-2}$ is $2\left(D_{n-4}+2D_{n-3}+D_{n-2}\right)$ and not just $\left(D_{n-4}+2D_{n-3}+D_{n-2}\right)$: shouldn't there be just four cases for $\zeta_{n-1}\cap \zeta_{n-2}$?

Comment: @Colorblind97,no ,these are the cases:  $$\sigma(n-1)=n,\sigma(n-3)=n-2$$ or $$\sigma(n-1)=n,\sigma(n-3)\ne n-2$$ or $$\sigma(n-1) \ne n,\sigma(n-3)=n-2$$ or $$\sigma(n-1) \ne n,\sigma(n-3)\ne n-2$$ or  $$\sigma(n-1)=n-2,\sigma(n-3)=n$$ or $$\sigma(n-1)=n-2,\sigma(n-3)\ne n$$ or $$\sigma(n-1) \ne n-2,\sigma(n-3)=n$$ or $$\sigma(n-1) \ne n-2,\sigma(n-3)\ne n$$

Comment: The case $\sigma(n-1)=n-2,\sigma(n-3)=n$ is already counted in $\sigma(n-1) \ne n,\sigma(n-3)\ne n-2$. In fact, using the relation $D_{n}=(n-1)(D_{n-1}+D_{n-2})$ we get that $\left(D_{n-4}+2D_{n-3}+D_{n-2}\right)=\frac{D_{n-1}}{n-2}+\frac{D_{n-2}}{n-3}$ which is exactly what Ewan Delanoy got for $|C|$.

Comment: @Colorblind97,Thanks for the point,indeed all of the next four cases are counted by $\sigma(n−1) \ne n,\sigma(n−3) \ne n−2$ and the formula should be  $$D_{n}-\frac{3D_{n}}{n-1}+\frac{3D_{n-1}}{n-2}\tag{$n\ge4$}$$Whcih is derived by removing all the next four cases (by removing the coefficient $2$ in $2\left(D_{n-4}+2D_{n-3}+D_{n-2}\right)$ )

Answer (score 2):

Here is a presentation which is both simpler and more systematic than your original attempt.

In what follows, $\Delta(X)$ denotes the set of all derangements on $X$ for any set $X$, and we also write $\Delta_n$ for $\Delta_{[n]}$ where $[n]=1,2,\ldots,n$. For $\sigma \in \Delta(X)$ and $x\in X$, let $S_x(\sigma)$ be the permutation on $X\setminus \lbrace x \rbrace$ which coincides with $\sigma$ everywhere except on $\sigma^{-1}(x)$, where it equals $\sigma(x)$. For $Z\subseteq \Delta (X)$, let $p_x(Z)=\lbrace \sigma \in Z | S_x(\sigma) \in \Delta(X\setminus \lbrace x \rbrace)\rbrace$, and $q_x(Z)=Z\setminus p_x(Z)=\lbrace \sigma \in Z |\sigma(\sigma(x))=x\rbrace$. We call the partition $Z=p_x(Z)\cup q_x(Z)$ the $x$-decomposition of $Z$.

Let us count the elements in $A=\zeta_n \cap \zeta_{n-1}$. We apply $n-1$-decomposition. We see that $q_{n-1}(A)$ is empty, so $|A|=|p_{n-1}(A)|$, but $p_{n-1}(A)$ is in bijection with $\lbrace \tau \in \Delta([n]\setminus \lbrace n-1 \rbrace) | \tau(n)=n-1 \rbrace$, so $|p_{n-1}(A)|=\frac{D_{n-1}}{n-2}$.

Replacing $n$ with $n-1$, we see that $B=\zeta_{n-1} \cap \zeta_{n-2}$ has the same cardinality, $\frac{D_{n-1}}{n-2}$.

Let us count the elements in $C=\zeta_n \cap \zeta_{n-2}$. We start by applying $n$-decomposition. Since $p_{n}(C)=\lbrace \tau \in \Delta([n-1]) | \tau(n-2)=n-3 \rbrace$, we have $|p_n(C)|=\frac{D_{n-1}}{n-2}$. So we need now to count the elements in $q_n(C)=\lbrace \sigma \in \Delta_n | \sigma(n)=n-1,\sigma(n-1)=n, \sigma(n-2)=n-3 \rbrace$, which is obviously in bijection with $\sigma \in \Delta_{n-2} | \sigma(n-2)=n-3 \rbrace$, so $|q_n(C)|=\frac{D_{n-2}}{n-3}$. Finally $|C|=\frac{D_{n-1}}{n-2}+\frac{D_{n-2}}{n-3}$.

Let us count the elements in $E=\zeta_n \cap \zeta_{n-1} \cap \zeta_{n-2}$. We start by applying $n-2$-decomposition.  We see that $q_{n-2}(E)$ is empty, so $|E|=|p_{n-2}(E)|$. We now need to count the elements in $F=p_{n-2}(E)$ where
$F=\lbrace \sigma \in \Delta([n]\setminus \lbrace n-2 \rbrace) | \sigma(n)=n-1,\sigma(n-1)=n-3 \rbrace$. By applying $n-1$-decomposition to $F$, we see that $F$ is in bijection with $\lbrace \sigma \in \Delta([n]\setminus \lbrace n-2,n-1 \rbrace) | \sigma(n)=n-3 \rbrace$. Thus $|E|=\frac{D_{n-2}}{n-3}$.

Finally, the answer to your question is

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
N &=& D_n-(|\zeta_n|+|\zeta_{n-1}|+|\zeta_{n-2}|-|A|-|B|-|C|+|E|) \\
&=&
D_n-3\frac{D_n}{n-1}+\frac{3D_{n-1}}{n-2}+\frac{D_{n-2}}{n-3}-\frac{D_{n-2}}{n-3} \\
&=& \frac{(n-4)D_n}{n-1}+\frac{3D_{n-1}}{n-2}+\frac{D_{n-2}}{n-3}-\frac{D_{n-2}}{n-3} \\
&=& \frac{(n-4)D_n}{n-1}+\frac{3D_{n-1}}{n-2} \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the proof,but I also need to know why my answer is wrong.

Comment: Frankly, as far as I'm concerned I refuse to "check" this very vague outline of a proof where too many details are missing. I'm not saying you didn't spend time and effort on your computation, but the effort is obviously lacking in your presentation of it (and this is probably why your question got no upvotes so far). Regarding your infamous "eight cases" for $\zeta_n \cap \zeta_{n-2}$, my guess is that just like me @Colorblind97 is still essentially clueless about how your complicated method works.

Comment: If you expect someone to check your eight cases for $\zeta_n \cap \zeta_{n-2}$, you could write out the bijection you use in each case, that should take no longer than the comment you wrote in answer to Colorblind97.

Comment: @ Ewan Delanoy,I agree,I will try to follow better methods to make my these kind of questions understandable (besdies I believe that what I've done is not neat at all,but I did not know how to make it better,that's why I've opened a bounty).

Comment: Just a little observation,the formula should be $$D_{n}-\frac{3D_{n}}{n-1}+\frac{3D_{n-1}}{n-2}$$For example for $n=4$ the number of such derangements is $3$ which coincides with what the formula gives us,or for $n=5$ it's $20$ which again coincides with what formula gives us.(I've written all of such derangements for $n=4,5$,if you want to see them,let me know.

Comment: I added a proof of your formula and corrected a typo in the process. Thanks for the correction

Comment: @ Ewan Delanoy,You are welcome,Also I figured out why my first formula was wrong,indeed all of the next four cases are counted by $\sigma(n−1)\ne n,\sigma(n−3) \ne n−2$ and the formula should be
$$D_{n}-\frac{3D_{n}}{n-1}+\frac{3D_{n-1}}{n-2}=\frac{\left(n-\color{red}{4}\right)D_{n}}{n-1}+\frac{3D_{n-1}}{n-2}$$
Which is derived by removing all the next four cases (by removing the coefficient $2$ in $2(D_{n−4}+2D_{n−3}+D_{n−2})$ )

Comment: I upvote,and please check the formula again :)

Comment: Corrected, thanks again :-)

Comment: @ Ewan Delanoy,you are welcome again :).

Comment: @EwanDelanoy: Result verified. Nice solution (+1).

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Thanks for your patience and interest.